# Problems arising while adding a new content type 

Tags: database

In my website, I have created 42 different content types. I want to add one more content type. I can create the content type, but I am unable to add content in it.

After creating a new content type, when I click on the link of the new content type, the whole site CSS is getting scattered. After deleting the new content type everything is getting normal.
Secondly, if add any new module the same problem is arising.

I have looked into this matter, and I found that in there are no new database table created when added a nee content type, or installing a new module.

May you please suggest me what could be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to drupal.se, Please refrain from including personal details such as your mail address in the future.

Comment: 42 content types seem like a lot. Is each content type unique and you cant leverage references / field collections?